# Bootstrap is not hit to HTML

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap is not hit to HTML.
I use Flat UI's Bootstrap.
I wrote in index.html like

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './bootflat.github.io/bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css' %}">

    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 70px;
      }

      .my-form {
        width: 640px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .my-form {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      .errorlist li {
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      .errorlist {
        color: red;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <p class="navbar-text">Hello</p>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <p class="navbar-text">{{  user.get_username }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I designate folder path which has Flat UI like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './bootflat.github.io/bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css' %}">` but the design is not changed.I accessed http://localhost:8000/static/bootflat.github.io/bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css,but Page not found (404)　Request Method:   GET Request URL error happens.So I think path is wrong.
Directory structure is 
[image]

index.html is in accounts.accounts folder structure is [image]

What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: First follow some tutorial and learn the structure of django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to include STATICFILES_DIRS in your settings.py.
Add this line to your settings.py.

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bootflat.github.io'), ]
```

And then access the static files in templates by:

```
     {% static 'bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css' %}
```

STATICFILES_DIRS is used to specify the directories  to look for static files.

> Before this

You need to understand how django project structure works. For that follow some tutorials on that.

Comment: I first downvoted answer just to say that, you should have encouraged him to go through the working of django-project staructure. But now after I edited your answer I upvoted it. I hope you don't mind it.